# matching JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I don’t know a lot about programming,I am sure my approach to this is completely wrong, but I am trying to import JSON into python and then search it.  The JSON is coming from a bus tracker website. I mostly understand how to import the data but I don’t really get how to use it.  This is what I have now.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://bustracker.tulsatransit.org/Services/JSONPRelay.svc/GetRouteVehicleEstimates')
data = r.json()

stop = requests.get('http://bustracker.tulsatransit.org/Services/JSONPRelay.svc/GetStops')
stops = stop.json()


def stopname(id):
 for i in stops:
    if i['RouteStopID'] == id:
        return i['Description'], id
    else:
        return "i dont know", i['RouteStopID'], id        


for i in data:
 for i in i['Vehicles']:
    print i['Name']
    for i in i['Estimates']:
        u = i['RouteStopID']
        print stopname(i['RouteStopID']) , (i['SecondsToStop']/60)
```

I don’t understand how to go though the objects that are numbered. I used ‘for I’ but it seems messy and the wrong way? Ultimately I want to be able to list estimate times for a particular route.  Is there a way to assign the objects to a variable? So I could call say i[‘Name’] else where without the “for I” mess? would I make that into a function?

My other problem is that the estimate route JSON doesn’t include the description for the StopID Key.  Again don’t really know how to do this but I came up with the function def stopname to search the stopID and return the description. But it doesn’t seem to step through the different objects correctly.

I searched around but couldn't find any examples like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use the same variable in all your loops! There are other letters in the alphabet you know? ;-)

Comment: You can't use `for i in i`, and yes, there are more letters in the alphabet. I recommend a basic tutorial that explains how object iteration and for loops work in Python before trying to do this

Answer (score 0):

The json returned for the stops appears to be a list of dicts.  If I understand what you're asking, you'd like to be able to find a stop by id instead of asking is "is this the right object in the array?".

Transform the stops to be a dict, keyed on the RouteStopID:

```
stop_dict = {x['RouteStopID']: x for x in stops}  # Dictionary Comprehension
```

Then you can return the appropriate stop information in a single request, instead of looping through the list asking is this my stop?

For example, get stop ID 2 information:

```
stop_dict.get(2, 'Stop Id not found')
```